# to set domain to open with www in URL

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, web-hosting

How to configure domain to open like **www.domainname.com**
Currently it is opening as **domainname.com**

Host    --  Points To   --  TTL Actions

```
@   45.40.137.206   1/2 Hour
```

CName (Alias)

Host -- Points To  -- TTL   Actions

```
email   email.secureserver.net  1 Hour  
ftp     @                       1 Hour
www     @                       1/2 Hour
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust DNS settings for your domain. You don't need `CNAME` record, instead you should add two `A` records for both domains (with `www` and without it), pointing to the same IP.